# PHP: If Statement not loading

Tags: php

I'm trying to add to the code below an if statement:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
    {
        $line = explode(',', $lines[$i]);
        if(trim($line[1])!='')
        {
            $csv_content .= trim($line[1]) . ';';
            $csv_content .= (intval(trim($line[8])) < 0 ? "0" : trim($line[8])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[6])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[7])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= '1' . '
';
            }
            unset($line);
        }
```

I have changed to:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
    {
        $line = explode(',', $lines[$i]);
        if(trim($line[1])!='')
        {
            $csv_content .= trim($line[1]) . ';';
            if(trim($line[1]) = 'XXXX') {$csv_content .= "10" . ';'; }
                else
                {$csv_content .= (intval(trim($line[8])) < 0 ? "0" : trim($line[8])) . ';';
                }
            $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[6])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[7])) . ';';
            $csv_content .= '1' . '
';


}
        unset($line);
    }
```

So if the Vaule of Line1 is "XXXX" the the next line should be "10", if not run the line  `$csv_content .= (intval(trim($line[8])) < 0 ? "0" : trim($line[8])) . ';';` instead

But the page is not loading, clearly I got something wrong, can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Use the == operator to check if values are equal: I fixed this in your if statement. Also, try to keep your code tidy and formatted, it will make it much easier to spot simple mistakes like this yourself.

```
for($i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    $line = explode(',', $lines[$i]);
    if(trim($line[1]) != '') {
        $csv_content .= trim($line[1]) . ';';
        if(trim($line[1]) == 'XXXX') {
             $csv_content .= "10" . ';'; 
        } else {
              $csv_content .= (intval(trim($line[8])) < 0 ? "0" : trim($line[8])) . ';';
        }
        $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[6])) . ';';
        $csv_content .= twoDecs(trim($line[7])) . ';';
        $csv_content .= '1' . '';
     }
 unset($line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did have that, but it did not work. Page loads ok, but in the output "xxxx" has 0 instead of 10.  . Thanks